# Pass parameter from one shell script to another

Tags: shell-script

I have two shell scripts namely `test1.sh` and `test2.sh`
I have to call `test2.sh` from `test1.sh`
For `test1.sh` I need to pass one parameter as a command line argument
and for `test2.sh` I need to pass a parameter at the prompt.

Code sample:

```
$ cat test2.sh
echo "enter id value"
<br>read id
#do some processing here
```

How do I call `test2.sh` from `test1.sh`?

**I can not edit test2.sh file here**

Answer (score 2):

if `test2.sh` is in the same directory, it's as simple as

file: `test1.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
...
echo 5 | ./test2.sh
```

`man read` has the opening:

```
read -- read a line from standard input
```

perhaps you were just missing the *dot slash* `./`, which is required for finding the script in the current directory. Alternatively, you can have your `$PATH` variable point to the folder containing `test2.sh`. Then `./` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

in test1.sh

```
echo whatever | test2.sh
```